# return code 10 means in the R documentation

Tags: r, condor

I have group of R jobs that should be submitted to the condor when I submit the jobs to the condor, they don't run and when I checked the Sched Log files the jobs are exiting with status code 10. Can anyone explain the meaning of this?

Here is my submit file:

```
# Submit file for combining the output

universe = vanilla

Executable = C:\Progra~1\R\R-2.11.1-x64\bin\Rscript.exe

getenv = true

transfer_executable = true

Output = AddTwo.out

Log = AddTwo.log

error = AddTwo.error


input = AddTwo.R

arguments = AddTwo.R

queue
```

Here is my Sched Log file:

```
04/21 16:20:06 IWD: C:\condor\execute\dir_280

04/21 16:20:06 Input file: C:\condor\execute\dir_280\AddTwo.R

04/21 16:20:06 Output file: C:\condor\execute\dir_280\AddTwo.out

04/21 16:20:06 Error file: C:\condor\execute\dir_280\AddTwo.error

04/21 16:20:06 Renice expr "10" evaluated to 10

04/21 16:20:06 About to exec C:\condor\execute\dir_280\condor_exec.exe 
sim_boot_omega_3_1_3.R

04/21 16:20:06 Create_Process succeeded, pid=2644

04/21 16:20:06 Process exited, pid=2644, status=10
```

Any Ideas on this are aprreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My submit script looks almost like that, except that I have

```
 transfer_executable = FALSE
```

That way Condor doesn't make a copy of it into the execute directory.